# Mystery Device On Network

Tags: windows

I keep seeing this mystery device when I look at Network in Windows. It's always a Samsung Nexus 10. Its name always changes. It's possible one of my relatives has a Nexus 10 but he's rarely here. I've even changed the password and it still shows up. I don't have a smart phone, let alone a Samsung device. If I check my DHCP leases on my router, it's not a device on there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the free utility [SoftPerfect Network Scanner](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networkscanner/).

After putting in the network range and hitting "Start Scanning" it will give you all the devices on your network. You'll find the IP of your mystery device and possibly which services are open on it.

It could be a phone with a static IP address so it doesn't request a IP from your DHCP-router. But if you changed your WiFi-password that seems unlikely.

It could also be a device still in the cache of your computer (Is it showing up in the Network of other computer too? and did you reboot?) or in the cache of the "Master Browser". The "Master Browser" is a computer or device in your network which is ["elected"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959896.aspx) to keep all the names. This could be any of your computers and can change at any time. It can take some time before such device is cleared from the network. (You could try restarting all your computers and devices, including phones, media players and routers, on the network to speed things up)

If the Network Scanner does not show the device you can rest assured it is no longer on your network.

[image: Network Scanner]

Comment: Nothing unusual with the scanner. As I said it changes its name frequently. Device info seems to change. It's still Samsung but it changed to generic info. Its name is now... Mandy Rogers Coyle? Refreshed, now it's gone. At some point it'll come back.

Comment: Try to do the scan at the moment it comes back. If its not there it's a "Master Browser" problem. It could be another device (laptop or something) which connects to your network and "becomes" the "Master Browser" and **it** has knowledge of a device from its previous connected network and broadcasts this name as a connected device. If the netscanner does not show the phantom device you need to find out **which** computer is "Master Browser" at that moment.

Comment: BTW I don't know if there is an easier way to determine the "Master Browser" but you can check [here](http://scottiestech.info/2009/02/14/how-to-determine-the-master-browser-in-a-windows-workgroup/). **Another** thing you could try is changing your WORKGROUP-name. If it's something common then what i said about another computer connecting and giving wrong names in your network becomes very plausible. Especially if that computer comes from another network with the same workgroup-name.

Comment: Never mind, it's back.

**Changing the Workgroup did not fix it.**

Comment: I take it, you don't have a VPN or Hamachi installed (a.k.a. connected to a remote network)? How many devices are connected according to Netscanner? You could try turning them off one by one until you know which is "Master Browser" and had the weird names. (I also take it you don't know Mandy Rogers Coyle :) Do you get anything if you enter (double click) the device in Network?

Comment: I just thought of something else. Besides possibly a "Master Browser" problem it could also be guest access to you router. Does you router (and/or provider) provide guest access to your network. If your router itself is not setup for guest access it could still be a broadband modem (with WiFi) which is setup with guest access. Just a thought.